# DefaultSiteMapProvider returns empty site map even though Mvc.sitemap is processed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a problem with the [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/) project: My sitemap is always empty.

I have set up a `Mvc.sitemap`, set up the `web.config` entries. Debugging through the `DefaultSiteMapProvider` shows me that the .sitemap file is read and correctly processed. However, the returned sitemap is basically empty:

```xml
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>
            http://localhost:59933/
        </loc>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

A weird thing happens when stepping through the code, however. I step through the DefaultSiteMapProvider and watch the root node in the `root` variable. Near the end of the method the root node gets reset to an empty node when setting the `isBuildingSiteMap  = false`. I have no idea how this could possibly affect setting up the root node, but it happens consistently in my project.

Any help how to prevent the `root` node from being overwritten is appreciated. :)

---

Annotated excerpt from the DefaultSiteMapProvider, near the very end of the `BuildSiteMap` method (ll. 660 ff.):

```cs
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(/*...*/); // At this point the root node is correct
isBuildingSiteMap = false; // after executing this line, `root` gets reset to an empty node.
siteMapXml = null;
```

Mvc.sitemap:

```xml
<mvcSiteMap [...]>
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Test" controller="Listing" action="Index">
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

The `web.config` entry is straight from the [documentation page](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Registering-the-provider), only adjusted for the sitemap name.

Comment: Are you asking whey the Listing controller doesn't appear in the sitemap?

Comment: Basically, yes; but in my actual project I have several dynamic node provider, all of which's nodes do not appear in the generated sitemap, even though the provider are executed and correctly assemble nodes.
When stepping through the code in the debugger, the root node gets completely nuked at the mentioned line in the `DefaultSiteMapProvider` for some reason.

Comment: Could you post the dynamic node providers?

Comment: I put the three providers into this gist, along with the full, actual Mvc.sitemap (though it fails in the same way for the abovementioned sitemap, sans running the dynamic providers). https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5047048

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake I made is related to adding DefaultNamespaces to the ControllerBuilder. The broken line was:

```cs
ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("My.Framework.Web");
```

And should have been:

```cs
ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("My.Framework.Web.Controllers");
```

MVC never complained about this, and happily found my controller.

Hoever, once the building of the sitemap is finished, the DefaultSiteMapProvider behaves differently insofar as that IsAccessibleForUser() suddenly became a factor in determining the ChildNodes. The default provider checks if the controller for the node can be found and does not look in sub-namespaces (unless the namespace ends in `.*`, cf. `MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultControllerTypeResolver.IsNamespaceMatch(string requestedNamespace, string targetNamespace)`).

Because I did not use wildcards, but assumed the sitemap would work when MVC works, it bit me in my rear.